# iCloud storage recovery not deleting photo albums

Tags: ipad

Can I delete camera  roll and free up iCloud storage without deleting photos in my albums ?

Answer (score 1):

No. The camera roll is and is not just another album. Delete that and you delete all your photos, (though I don't believe it can be deleted), but I believe the albums will remain and be empty. Albums don't store extra copies of photos. When you create albums, these aren't filled with distinct copies of photos, but something similar to aliases or links — at least conceptually. Conversly, Deleting photos from albums does not actually delete the photos from your camera role. You have to delete photos by deleting the photos from your camera role. Albums don't really take up any space, or a very tiny amount of space... maybe dozens of kilobytes. Once an album is empty, it can be deleted.

---

On your iPhone, under Settings app/iCloud page, turn off photo syncing. Because there is no way to access iCloud other than in the background autosyncing, this should erase your photos from iCloud and leave them on your iPhone.

If you don't have your own computer, buy a largeish [usb thumb drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007960%20600082308%20600000482%20600000447&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Pagesize=100&Page=1) and find a friend with a Mac and have her download [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), connect your iPhone to her Mac with a sync cable, and have her transfer your photos to the usb thumb drive for you. Alternatively, if you have an iPhone 5, the [Lightning to SD Card Camera Reader](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD822ZM/A/lightning-to-sd-card-camera-reader) (or [usb version](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD821ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter?fnode=3a) w/usb thumb)and a decent sized [SD Card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007962%2050001404%20600006235%20600006236%20600006245&IsNodeId=1&Description=sd%20card&name=128GB&Order=BESTMATCH), 32-128GB, and a thumb-sized usb [SD Card Reader](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007766%20600031471%20600021094&IsNodeId=1&Description=usb%20sd%20card%20reader&name=USB%202.0&Order=BESTMATCH) for good measure. Use this combination to connect the SD Card to your iPhone and transfer your Photos to your SD Card periodically, to back them up or free up space on your iPhone. SD Cards are more expensive than USB thumb drives, but the advantage is the data is far more "durable," as these cards are [water-proof](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-cornwall-19660338) and nearly [indestructable](http://www.engadget.com/2011/11/27/canon-eos-1000d-washes-ashore-sd-card-reveals-it-was-lost-at-se/), while usb thumb drives are notoriously unreliable afa massive data corruption.

Apple's Camera Connection Kit was not fully compatible with iPhone 4, but I am seeing evidence that the new lightning camera adapters are compatible with iPhone 5. If anyone knows otherwise, please comment.

Comment: But how can I gain storage space by deleting photos and NOT lose pictures in my albums etc ? I am confused .

Comment: @TonyB : have a computer? Or a usb thumb drive and a freind with a computer? Forget about albums, pull your pictures down, store on [thumb drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007960%20600082308%20600000482%20600000447&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Pagesize=100&Page=1), delete photos from iCloud. Its nice to temp sync photos up in case u lose ur iPhone. But unless u want to purchase more space, iCloud is not ideal for large files like images. Go Pens!

Comment: @TonyB It is me who is confused.  I wasn't sure what albums/camera role you meant; for some reason, I thought these things were in iCloud, but obviously you mean on your iPhone. Refresh page in a few mins while I fix the answer.